# Deleting specific string matched logs from logstash

Tags: elk

I want to delete all the logs in logstash which has with /health or /healthcheck as part of message. What is the correct filter to use ?
Not sure if the below will work:

```
if "/health" in [message]
{
  drop{}
}
```

Sample log looks like this:

December 6th 2022, 12:02:00.081 a9075844753511eda1eb0242ac120002 S GET /health

I am trying to get the logs with the endpoints /health or /healthcheck to be dropped and not shown in Kibana

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use re-module in your workspace
Second, you can use built-in functions like `matchall()` or `findall()`.
And after that, it will return the index of the searched word and you can specify the string to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

When you only have a message field you can use

```
  if ([message] =~ "(health|healthcheck)" ) {
      drop {}
  }
```

Comment: In the message part I see "a9075844753511eda1eb0242ac120002 S GET /health" so in this scenario will this work??

Comment: logstash will remove all lines with a message containing health or healthcheck.